# I'm not receiving a message back on iOS while using Mqtt protocol with raspberry pi

Tags: python, ios, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I'm trying to send a data from RPI to iOS application
the message is showing on the RPI but its not in iOS

```
//this is the code on RPI
import paho.mqtt.client as MQTT
def connectionStatus(client, userdata, flag, rc):
print("Connecting...")
mqttClient.subscribe("rpi/hello")
def messageDecoder(client, userdata, msg):
message = msg.payload.decode(encoding='UTF-8')
 if message == "this is iPhone":
    print("Sending reply...")
    mqttClient.publish("rpi/world", "this is 3b+")
 clientName = "Pi"
 serverAddress = "192.168.1.101"
mqttClient = MQTT.Client(clientName)
mqttClient.on_connect = connectionStatus
mqttClient.on_message = messageDecoder
mqttClient.connect(serverAddress)
mqttClient.loop_forever()
```

here and the code on swift I've tried a lot of ways here can someone please help me solve this problem !

```
import UIKit
import CocoaMQTT
protocol didReceiveMessageDelegate {
func setMessage(message: String)}
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let mqttClient = CocoaMQTT(clientID: "iOS Device", host: "192.168.1.101", port: 1883)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


@IBAction func connect(_ sender: UIButton) {
    mqttClient.connect()
}


@IBAction func disconnect(_ sender: UIButton) {
    mqttClient.disconnect()
}

@IBOutlet weak var labelshow: UILabel!

@IBAction func send(_ sender: UIButton) {
    mqttClient.publish("rpi/hello", withString: "this is iphone")
    mqttClient.subscribe("rpi/world")

          }

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceiveMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16 ) {
    let messageDecoded = String(bytes: message.payload, encoding: .utf8)
    print("Did receive a message: \(messageDecoded!)")
 }

func setMessage(message: String) {
    labelshow.text = message}


}
```

Comment: im trying to show it in the UIlabel

Comment: You don't set the MQTT client delegate to your view controller

Comment: I did by.    protocol didReceiveMessageDelegate {
    func setMessage(message: String)
}
but still it doesn't show could you please help me im new to this

Comment: could you check if that is what you mean I edited it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your view controller as the MQTT client's `delegate` otherwise the `didReceiveMessage` delegate function won't be called.

You need to state that your class conforms to `CocoaMQTTDelegate` and then assign the delegate

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CocoaMQTTDelegate {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.mqttClient.delegate = self
    }
```

Comment: I did that it's giving me this error "Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'CocoaMQTTDelegate?'' and when I do still nothing shows !

Comment: You need to tell Swift that you class conforms to the delegate protocol.  See my edit.

Comment: whenever I sate CocoaMQTTDelegate it gives me an error saying :Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'CocoaMQTTDelegate'.  how do I solve it ? thanks in advance